# Why are there gaps in an imported .svg?

Tags: import, svg, vector-mapping

I've traced a bitmap of a political map in inkscape. I've even simplified the nodes of Russia and Canada to have less total nodes than e.g. Brazil.

[image]

However, Russia and Canada can't seem to import properly into blender, with or without the simplification.

[image]

I'm very confused about the reason or how to find anything about this problem online, so any hint would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check that the paths are closed, also make sure that there are no overlapping and/or intersecting sections..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Susu was correct in assuming that there are overlapping sections. More specifically, overlapping sections in which the same border crosses over or folds over itself kind of like if one would write the number 8. Intersecting with another path doesn't cause the evident gaps.